# Insert a vectorial image in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a project using WPF in visual studio 2017. I want to insert a vectorial image (.SVG for an example). How to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share some code so its easier to help you

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

> WPF doesn't have SVG support

However you can convert `svg` into `xaml` using SharpVector Library.

see for more information.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127039/SharpVectors-SVG-Reloaded-An-Introduction

internally it converts your `svg` element into `xaml` geometries.